# Ubuntu 18.04 apparantly offline? and yet I can browse fine

Tags: networking

So I got this VM up and running with Plex andNextcloud a while ago but I've not been happy with the plex performance so I wanted to move it from a snap install to a regular install but apparantly I can't install plexmediaserver because I'm offline??

Makes no sense to me - I can use the browser just fine as well as run apt updates and still access my nextcloud and plex installs

Anyone have any ideas?

my network icon in the top left says "wired unmanaged" and has a little x in the bottom right of the icon and if I click connect in the drop-dwon nothing happens...

Comment: That mostly worked - the first post (marked as solution) didn't change anything but I tried the 3rd one and that seems to have worked finally.

Comment: My apologies: I should have pointed you to that one when I posted the duplicate...  I haven't logged on in a week, so I'm behind on answering unanswered questions and upvoting the answered ones...  **;-)**  *Good to hear that answered your question...*  **+1** for sharing and marking the duplicate as the solution!